# Monitoring Azure websites IIS logging

Tags: iis, azure, web, blob, monitoring

Azure websites store IIS logs in blobs. I am writing utilities to get blob data periodically and monitor the server.

Problem here is, how can I optimize my code not to read same data again and again? I don't think I can read a blob store from a certain point. can I?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Blobs support range requests. So if you had read 254 bytes the previous time you could read from 255 to end of blob using the following syntax:

- Range: bytes=255-
- x-ms-range: bytes=255-

See for details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee691967.aspx